# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. Lock is being used everywhere how possible?

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, thread-safety, locking

This is a small program that only i am writing and using.

Now i am going to write code of all areas where i use the hashset that caused this problem

I don't understand how this is possible. This item is being used only at MainWindow

hsProxyList  is a hashset

```
  HashSet<string> hsProxyList = new HashSet<string>();
```

the error happened at below iteration

```
 lock (hsProxyList)
            {
    int irRandomProxyNumber = GenerateRandomValue.GenerateRandomValueMin(hsProxyList.Count, 0);
    int irLocalCounter = 0;
    foreach (var vrProxy in hsProxyList)
    {
       if (irLocalCounter == irRandomProxyNumber)
       {
       srSelectedProxy = vrProxy;
       break;
       }
         irLocalCounter++;
       }
    }
}
```

The other places where i use hsProxyList

I don't lock the object when i am getting its count - i suppose this would not cause any error but may be not correct - not fatally important

```
 lblProxyCount.Content = "remaining proxy count: " + hsProxyList.Count;
```

new

```
lock (hsProxyList)
{
    hsProxyList.Remove(srSelectedProxy);
}
```

new

```
lock (hsProxyList)
{
    hsProxyList = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var vrLine in File.ReadLines(cmbBoxSelectProxy.SelectedItem.ToString()))
    {
        hsProxyList.Add(vrLine);
    }
}
```

As can be seen i am using lock everywhere. This is a multi threading software. All hsProxyList is being used in MainWindow.xaml.cs - it is a C# WPF application

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: could you provide a complete compilable example?

Comment: @SLaks it doesn't show. How can i enable it to show this kind of errors ?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Default I am using visual studio 2012

Comment: Go to Debug > Exceptions > check Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Comment: @Default it is checked for user handled. should i also check thrown ?

Comment: `All hsProxyList is being used in MainWindow.xaml.cs` - are you  saying all access happens on UI thread - OR - are you creating other threads who's source is also in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`? if former than locking is not required - your problem is some thing else.

Comment: what is `srSelectedProxy`? just a string? or is it a property which could modify `hsProxyList`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is where you have

```
lock (hsProxyList)
{
    hsProxyList = new HashSet<string>();
    // etc
}
```

All locks are on a particular object, however you're changing the object when you do `hsProxyList = new HashSet<string>();` so the object that the variable hsProxyList refers to is no longer locked.

Comment: very valid point :) that may be why it is not happening all the time but rarely.

Comment: changed code according to this. instead new i am going to use clear. lets see now :)

Comment: well this solved my problem for those who may wonder :) thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here.  The first, which has already been pointed out is that you're locking on the hash set whilst also changing the object `hsProxyList` points to:

```
lock (hsProxyList)
{
    hsProxyList = new HashSet<string>();
    // hsProxyList is no longer locked.
}
```

The second (and more subtle) problem, is that you're assuming that `Count` does not require a lock.  This is not a safe assumption.  Firstly, you don't know how `HashSet` has implemented it.  The fact that [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb355720.aspx) is an `O(1)` operation indicates there is a member variable that keeps track of the count.  This means that on `Add` or `Remove` this variable must be updated.  An implementation of `Add` might look something like:

```
bool Add( T item ) {
    this.count++;
    // Point A.
    addItemToHashSet(item);
}
```

Note that the `count` variable is incremented and *then* the item is added.  If the thread calling `Add` is interupted at **point A** and your other thread that calls `Count` is executed you will receive a count that is higher than the number of actual elements (`count` has been incremented, but `addItemToHashSet` has not).

This may not have any serious consequences, but if you're iterating over `Count` elements it could cause a crash.  Similar behaviour is also likely when calling `Remove`.

Comment: thanks steve. so you mean that getting only count may crash application did i understand correct ? i know that the number may be incorrect but it is not important in my case. also after above answer software worked perfectly for hours so i guess that was the problem.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG The lock on the changing object is definitely the cause of your error message.  I wanted to make you aware of a more subtle issue that won't generate error messages, but could give you strange and difficult to reproduce behaviour.  Because you're just displaying `Count` it's almost certainly not going to cause an issue.  However, you should be aware that it is not a safe thing to do in a lot of circumstances.